# AnchorError caused by account: seller_trade_state. A seeds constraint was violated. error in seller trade state in auctioneer

Tags: solana, metaplex

I'm getting this error in selling in auctioneer sdk

```
'Program neer8g6yJq2mQM6KbnViEDAD4gr3gRZyMMf4F2p3MEh invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Sell',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program log: AnchorError caused by account: seller_trade_state. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated.',
    'Program neer8g6yJq2mQM6KbnViEDAD4gr3gRZyMMf4F2p3MEh consumed 26150 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program neer8g6yJq2mQM6KbnViEDAD4gr3gRZyMMf4F2p3MEh failed: custom program error: 0x7d6'
```

i'm finding seller trade sate like this

```
 const sellerTradeState = await  anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [
      Buffer.from('auction_house'),
      publicKey.toBuffer(),
      aH.toBuffer(),
      associatedAddress.toBuffer(),
      WRAPPED_SOL_MINT.toBuffer(),
      mint.toBuffer(),
      new BN (10000000).toBuffer('le',8),
      new BN (Math.ceil(1)).toBuffer('le',8),
      
    ],
    AUCTION_HOUSE_PROGRAM_ID,
  );
```

I tried many arguments like `u64::MAX`'s value and regular buyer price, but every time pda is wrong. what should i change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it by using this as trade state.

```
async function getAuctionHouseTradeState( 
    auctionHouse, 
    wallet, 
    tokenAccount, 
    treasuryMint, 
    tokenMint, 
    tokenSize, 
    buyPrice 
  ) { 
    return await PublicKey.findProgramAddress( 
      [ 
        Buffer.from('auction_house'), 
        wallet.toBuffer(), 
        auctionHouse.toBuffer(), 
        tokenAccount.toBuffer(), 
        treasuryMint.toBuffer(), 
        tokenMint.toBuffer(), 
        new BN(buyPrice).toArrayLike(Buffer, "le", 8), 
        new BN(tokenSize).toArrayLike(Buffer, "le", 8), 
      ], 
      AUCTION_HOUSE_PROGRAM_ID 
    ); 
  }

  const [sellerTradeState, tradeBump] = await getAuctionHouseTradeState( 
    aH, 
    publicKey, 
    associatedAddress, 
    WRAPPED_SOL_MINT, 
    mint, 
    1, 
    "18446744073709551615" 
  );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution. Have you managed to Cancel the listing of the Auction? I’m experiencing this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73167995/metaplex-canceling-an-english-auction-made-by-auctioneer the time of auction ended and my NFT is now stuck. Been trying to look for a way to Cancel it for some days with no luck

Comment: Just replied to your question. see if that works

Answer (score 0):

You need to check ur seeds. This is how the seeds seems at [Sell instruction](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/auction-house/program/src/sell/mod.rs#L15)

[image: seeds for seller_trade_state]

Where PREFIX is ["auction_house"](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/auction-house/program/src/constants.rs#L1), so at least that seed is incorrect. Make sure to check the rest of seeds in order to provide a correct PDA to avoid that error

Comment: ```
const sellerTradeState = await  anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [
      Buffer.from('auction_house'),
      publicKey.toBuffer(),
      aH.toBuffer(),
      associatedAddress.toBuffer(),
      WRAPPED_SOL_MINT.toBuffer(),
      mint.toBuffer(),
      new BN(1000000000).toBuffer('le',8),
      new BN (Math.ceil(1)).toBuffer('le',8),
      
    ],
    AUCTION_HOUSE_PROGRAM_ID,
  );
```
still the same error

Comment: Its hard to know what is incorrect if you dont provide the full code, because you are not using an instance of AH to provide its mint or the treasury_mint for example

Comment: https://github.com/Maverick9081/Auctioneer

full code