# Metaplex - Canceling an (English) Auction made by Auctioneer

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, metaplex

I have a question about canceling auctions in the Metaplex’s Auction House.

I’m currently creating an Auction with the following instruction:

```
const accounts = {
  auctionHouseProgram,
  listingConfig,
  wallet,
  tokenAccount,
  metadata,
  authority,
  auctionHouse,
  auctionHouseFeeAccount,
  sellerTradeState,
  freeSellerTradeState,
  auctioneerAuthority,
  ahAuctioneerPda,
  programAsSigner
};

const args {
  tradeStateBump,
  freeTradeStateBump,
  programAsSignerBump,
  auctioneerAuthorityBump,
  tokenSize,
  startTime,
  endTime,
  reservePrice,
  minBidIncrement,
  timeExtPeriod,
  timeExtDelta,
  allowHighBidCancel,
}

Auctioneer.createSellInstruction(acounts, args);
```

Is there any way to cancel a listed auction of this type?

I know that other types of listings such as `AuctionHouse.createSellInstruction` (https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/auction-house/js/src/generated/instructions/sell.ts) do have a Cancel Instruction, and I’ve used them before.

But how can I cancel the English Auction type? Is it even possible? Like, what if I accidently made an Auction last for years, or put a wrong Listing Configuration value?

All Cancel instructions take as an argument the `buyerPrice`. But in this case there is no `buyerPrice`, it rather uses `reservePrice`.

I've tried to pass the `buyerPrice` as `18446744073709551615` to try to execute the `Auctioneer.createCancelInstruction`, which is the same `buyerPrice` value I used to create the `TradeState` for listing it. But I get the following error:

```
2: "Program log: AnchorError caused by account: token_account. Error Code: AccountOwnedByWrongProgram. Error Number: 3007. Error Message: The given account is owned by a different program than expected."
3: "Program log: Left:"
4: "Program log: 11111111111111111111111111111111"
5: "Program log: Right:"
6: "Program log: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
```

Also...

1. Is it possible to create a `ListingReceipt` for this type of
   listing? I want to keep track of creation date, canceled date, etc.
2. When an Auction for an item has ended and failed to bid cause no bidders or any other reason, if I try to list it again for another auction I get: `Address { address: GkX7ZE4sz6mtvueoWT6KGpjZLUd3wkohy3ha3VZNh2Fz, base: None } already in use` So I believe cancelation is needed. Cause now it’s on a weird unknown status where Auction has ended due to time constraints and Token cannot be listed again.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel your listing Using [THIS](https://github.dev/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/tree/master/auction-house/program/src).

1. You can you normal listing receipts of AH for this as well.
2. The previous account should be closed in order to create a new listing. In order to close that account you need to cancel listing or the Nft should be sold.

Comment: Are you sure it's possible to cancel? I'm able to do it for NON-time-based auctions, but when I use time-based auctions. Transaction fails. And for the listing receipt, have you really created a listing for time-base auctions? Same, I've made them for NON-time-based auctions, but for time-based auctions I'm getting: `PublicKeyMismatch. Error Number: 6000`.

Comment: I've sent you a Friend Request on Discord, I think we can help each other solve this and post an answer here once we find it.